# MySQL / AWS RDS : ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have the newest version of mysql installed , along with mysql workbench:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

When i try to run  `$ mysql -h pgdb6.cy6onqf2jyfs.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin`, the process hangs for a while, and then kicks back the error :

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pgdb6.cy6onqf2jyfs.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (110)
```

I cant connect to the mysql server on aws. I have changed my mysql password. I have uninstalled and reinstalled mysql a few times. Im not sure what im missing!

Here is my setup on aws:

[image]

here are my security groups and inbound rules

[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how AWS MYSQL works, however you could see if there is a place to whitelist your IP Address. It seems as though it is rejecting you because your IP is not able to connect possibly. Just trying to help debug :)

Comment: Please Edit your question to show your Inbound Security Group settings for the Amazon RDS database, and also the setting of the `Publicly Accessible` option. Are you running that command from your own computer, or an Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: trying to run locally @John Rotenstein

Comment: The DNS Name of `pgdb6.cy6onqf2jyfs.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com` does not resolve to an IP address. (You can test this by pinging that name to force it to resolve -- not to reach the database, but just to get the IP address. For me it says `unknown host`.) If that is the correct DNS Name, and it is set to `Public accessibility = Yes`, then it should resolve to an IP address. That's the cause (or at least the _first_ cause) of the problem you'll need to solve. Don't know what would cause such a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I'm fairly new to AWS. After a lot of research, found out that adding a new inbound rule for the security group worked. Below are the steps,

1. Select the running EC2 instance.
2. Navigate to  security Groups and then to inbound rules.
3. Edit Inbound Group.
4. Add Rule.
5. Under Type, Select "MYSQL/Aurora", Protocol : "All", Port range "All", Source "Custom", then add "0.0.0.0/0" and save rule.
6. Do the same for the outbound rule.

Go back to terminal or just connect through AWS Console. This worked for me.